# Keep an ongoing notification even when the app is closed

Tags: android

I have an app which frequently uploads the device location to a server.

Uploading location is done in a repeating alarm, and it works even when user exits the app and clears it from recent app list.

User can stop the app from uploading location by pressing a button on the app.

I need to show an ongoing notification to the user indicating that app is alive and it is currently uploading the location. I used an ongoing notification, (`NotificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)`), but this notification goes away as soon as user exits the app and removes it from recent apps.

I know that keeping the notification should be possible because there are apps which do this. For an example, uTorrent app and WiFi ADB app does this.

Does anyone know a way to keep the notification even when the app is closed?

Comment: Can you have a service running in the background?

Answer (score 2):

Start a sticky Service. The service is restarted instantly after the user (force) closes the app when removing it from the recents list. The Service is also started directly after booting the device, so the sticky notification never goes away. Please keep in mind that a sticky notification never going away may upset some users.

OngoingNotificationService.class:

```
public class OngoingNotificationService extends Service {
    
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Check if notification should be shown and do so if needed

    }
}
```

OngoingNotificationServiceStarter.class:

```
public class OngoingNotificationServiceStarter extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, OngoingNotificationService.class);
        context.startService(i);

    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest>

   ...

   <application>

        ...

        <service android:name=".OngoingNotificationService" />

        <receiver android:name=".OngoingNotificationServiceStarter">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

   </application>

</manifest>
```